# Laravel - Route to subdomain with session data

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel for my project, i have two subdomains where both point to the same app, app.project.com,user.project.com

When the user logs in on app.project.com i want to route him to user.project.com but the issue is that sessions aren't transfered so the user is router to user.project.com but faces the login page again

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

in config/session.php make sure this is found

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

and in .env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.project.com
```